# Mongodb Query to find birthdays based on the todays date using typescript express

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongodb-query

Whats the proper approach for the above if I cant use $where ? How can I compare an ISO date based on its day and month only. What if i want to find past and upcoming 10 birthdays?  My User Model.

```
 presentEvent = await User.find({
      dob: {
        "$month": today.getMonth(),
        "$dayOfMonth": today.getDay()
      }
    });
```

```
Error: Can't use $dayOfMonth with Date.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
presentEvent = await User.find({
  $expr: {$and:
  [
    { $eq: [{$dayOfMonth: "$dob"}, today.getDate()]},
    { $eq: [{$month: "$dob"}, today.getMonth() + 1]} 
  ]}
});
```

Note, `getDay()` returns the day of the week, i.e. number between 0 (Sunday) and 6 (Saturday)